# How to find highest high lowest low values from a range of cell values for every n cells values with google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, numbers

google app script to find highest high and lowest low values from an array of cell values for every n cell values from a range in google sheet. suppose the values in A column are as - A1 1 A2 12 A3 8 A4 2 A5 5 A6 9 A7 6 A8 8 A9 11 A10 10 A11 7 A12 12 A13 5 A14 2 A15 15

As per logic the first highest high value of first five cell values of columan A is as 12, which is on B column's first cell and the first lowest low value of five cell values of columan A is as 1, which is on C column and so on for other call values with every five cell values to find the highest high and lowest low values from A column top to bottom.

[Here's the screenshot of google sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xeNr.png)

Comment: why did you delete your previous request https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72195926/need-app-script-to-get-the-highest-high-and-the-lowest-low-values-in-google-shee and re-create whithout any more informations? Where is your script trial?

Comment: this can be done by a simple formula, why do you want a script?

Answer (score 0):

#### Highs and Lows of Active Range List

```
function highsandlows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rgl = sh.getActiveRangeList();
  const fl = rgl.getRanges().map(r => r.getValues().flat()).flat();
  const l = fl.sort((a,b) => a - b)[0];
  const h = fl.sort((a,b) => b - a)[0];
  Logger.log('high: %s, low: %s',h,l);
}
```

Comment: Thanks it gives only highest and lowest value of selected  range cell values.  Suppose to be its like push  all cell values  of A column into an array and using for loop with length of n values (here n  value is 5) within for loop of the array of A column cell values to find the high low.